# nss_ldap: "getent passwd" works, "getent passwd <username>" fails?

Tags: ldap

I've installed nss_ldap, edited nsswitch.conf to use ldap; here is my `/etc/ldap.conf` contents:

```
host ldap.<mycompany>.com
base o=<mycompany>,c=<cc>
bind_policy soft
nss_reconnect_tries 4
nss_reconnect_sleeptime 1
nss_reconnect_maxsleeptime 16
nss_reconnect_maxconntries 2
```

When I do

```
getent passwd
```

I get a correct view of all the usernames in the company. But if I do

```
getent passwd <some user>
```

with a known valid username, nothing is returned, as if the user didn't exist. (it works for local non-ldap users)

If I compile nss_ldap with debug enabled, the former prints out a lot of debugging messages like:
    nss_ldap: ==> do_result
    nss_ldap: <== do_result
    nss_ldap: ==> _nss_ldap_assign_userpassword
    nss_ldap: <== _nss_ldap_assign_userpassword

but the latter does not show anything. There's nothing in syslog either.

This quite puzzles me. Where should I start looking for the problem ? any ideas where it could be ?

The client is running Gentoo linux, nss_ldap-264. The LDAP server is out of my control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you use nscd, the naming caching daemon ? It could have a negative-cache of the user, in which case running `/usr/sbin/nscd -i passwd` would invalidate the cache and cause a re-fetch.

`getent passwd` works because it bypasses nscd.

Comment: Good catch, thanks! For some reason, "nscd -i passwd" did not fix the problem, but restarting nscd did...